# How does one write a shorthand setter in PHP?

Tags: php, shortcut

I'm curious is there a way to write a shorthand setter in PHP. My primary quest when writing code is to make it as tight as possible and I think the following is kind of cumbersome:

```
$value = "Which array do I go in?";
if(true)
    $arr_1[] = $value;
else
    $arr_2[] = $value;
```

Is there a better way to write that? I tried to use the shorthand if:

```
(true)?$arr_1[]:$arr_2[] = "Which array do I go in?";
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Anyone have any cool tricks for this type of situation?

Thanks!

Comment: `$cond == true ? $arr['first'][] = $value : $arr['second'][] = $value;` maybe? Why two different variables in the first place?

Comment: Don't confuse tight with efficient... normally tight means highly efficient code, which doesn't necessarily mean as few characters in the source files as possible

Comment: Feel free to downvote me to hell, but this short-hand has no place in production environments where others will have to dissect your code one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option (e.g. if you can't/don't want to use globals).

```
${$cond?'arr_1':'arr_2'}[] = $value;
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no shorthand for what you are trying to do.  Also you should realize that making code "as tight as possible" often comes at the cost of readability.

EDIT: There is some ugly hacks to do what you want, but I would strongly recommend against.  E.g.:

```
$GLOBALS[cond ? 'varname1' : 'varname2'] = $value;
```

Comment: How the hell did this horrible thing get 6 upvotes in 45 minutes?!

Comment: I agree Theodore, not to be nit-picky but isn't the use of "GLOBALS" frowned upon?

Comment: @thiesdiggity Damn straight! IF i *ever* see this code in something I'm working in, just be prepared for some trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Another hack would be:

```
$arr = ($cond ? &$arr_1 : &$arr_2);
$arr[] = 'Which array do I go in';
```

it's two lines but it doesn't require global and would work in a function.  However for readability it is probably better to use an if statement.  (Note: the & is making a reference to the variable, which is why this works).  Another (which might make you understand HOW the ternary operator works) would be:

```
$cond ? $arr_1[] = $value : $arr_2[] = $value;
```

You see the ternary operator only evaluates (runs the code path) of the successful evaluation (on the right side of the ? if true, on the right side of : if false).  However if you think this is faster than using 'if' you are wrong, your less 'tight' code will actually perform [better](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/48/the-php-ternary-operator-fast-or-not).

Comment: +1 for the reference that ternary performance is actually slower